# Why doesn't pyinstaller work with the time package?

Tags: python, time, pip, pyinstaller

Am I really the first one to wonder why the time.sleep() function wont work in a pyinstaller .exe?
It just keeps on going with either no or an miniscule amount of wait time. It also messes with the keyboard and the mouse pip packages (the input-event loops).

How can I fix this issue? Are there alternatives?

Comment: let's see some code

Comment: Yeah, this is ambiguous. It is more likely than not that your code is the problem, not pyinstaller.